# AFNetworking upload PDF file

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I'm trying to upload a pdf file with AFNetworking 3.0 to a server,

My pdf file was send in NSData in the formData
but it's returning me this error :

```
NSError * domain: @"com.alamofire.error.serialization.response" - code: 18446744073709550605
```

There my code :

```
-(void)uploadPDFFile{


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"URLREQUEST" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:self->originalDataPDF name:@"fileName" fileName:self->fileNamePDF mimeType:@"application/pdf"];
        
       
        }
        error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] 
    initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration 
    defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
  

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
  progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
      // This is not called back on the main queue.
      // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
      
  }
  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
  if (error) {
          NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);    
      } else {

               NSLog(@"WORKING ");

             }
      }];

    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

When print the responseObject the error Log return me this :

> 406 Not Acceptable
>
> ## Not
> Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested
> resource could not be found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 406
> Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying to use an
> ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The issue is on the parsing of the returned value: it's not valid JSON. There could be an error, but it might give usefull input, so let's read it. It's been a while since I played with AFNetworking, but, could you set instead: `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]`, and print `responseObject`, and if `responseObject` is a `NSData` (which I think it should be), print `[[NSString alloc]] initWithData: responseObject encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

Comment: I update my post

Comment: Now, we a have a clear error which was given ini HTML. I don't know what's the issue, could be a wrong/missing header parameters. Check with API dev maybe?